# Wait for specific server response command code in IRC

Tags: python, events, irc

I've made an IRC bot in Python and I've been trying to figure out a way to wait for an IRC command and return the message to a calling function for a while now. I refuse to use an external library for various reasons including I'm trying to learn to make these things from scratch. Also, I've been sifting through documentation for existing ones and they're way too comprehensive. I'me trying to make a simple one.

For example:

```
def who(bot, nick):
    bot.send('WHO %s' % nick)
    response = ResponseWaiter('352')  # 352 - RPL_WHOREPLY
    return response.msg
```

Would return a an object of my Message class that parses IRC messages to the calling function:

```
def check_host(bot, nick, host):
    who_info = who(bot, nick)
    if who_info.host == host:
        return True
    return False
```

I have looked at the reactor pattern, observer pattern, and have tried implementing a hundred different event system designs for this to no avail. I'm completely lost.

Please either provide a solution or point me in the right direction. There's got to be a simple way to do this.

So what I've done is use grab messages from my generator (a bot method) from the bot's who method. The generator looks like this:

```
def msg_generator(self):
    ''' Provides messages until bot dies '''
    while self.alive:
        for msg in self.irc.recv(self.buffer).split(('\r\n').encode()):
            if len(msg) > 3:
                try: yield Message(msg.decode())
                except Exception as e:
                    self.log('%s %s\n' % (except_str, str(e)))
```

And now the bot's who method looks like this:

```
def who(self, nick):
    self.send('WHO %s' % nick)
    for msg in self.msg_generator():
        if msg.command == '352':
            return msg
```

However, it's now taking control of the messages, so I need some way of relinquishing the messages I'm not using for the who method to their appropriate handlers.

My bot generally handles all messages with this:

```
def handle(self):
    for msg in self.msg_generator():
        self.log('◀    %s' % (msg))
        SpaghettiHandler(self, msg)
```

So any message that my SpaghettiHandler would be handling is not handled while the bot's who method uses the generator to receive messages.

It's working.. and works fast enough that it's hard to lose a message. But if my bot were to be taking many commands at the same time, this could become a problem. I'm pretty sure I'll find a solution in this direction, but I didn't create this as the answer because I'm not sure it's a good way, even when I have it set to relinquish messages that don't pertain to the listener.

Comment: I don't know python enough, but the problem is that you want messages to be handled while preserving the current stack. I suggest coroutines, re-entering some kind of event-loop is bad (what if the same same method is called somewhere below?). An other option is to take over the socket, read the messages, add them to a queue and process them later, when you got your message.

Comment: Okay, in Python I can do that with a generator. I'll edit my question to show what I've done following your advice.

Comment: Just a suggestion: implement a generator that uses your generator when a queue is empty, otherwise pop the first element of that queue. Push the items that you don't use to the queue.

Comment: Bear in mind that you have to handle cases like no `352` response to the WHO message ever arriving (perhaps their nick changed in the meantime and you received an error numeric instead).

Comment: @caf ..."Bear in mind"... How did you know? https://github.com/FrederickGarcia/Bearbot Yeah, after I wrote it I started to realize that and I looked at how many different error response codes there are for different things.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn, You were absolutely right about the co-routines. I'm using the trampoline pattern explained in https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b7R3-_ViNxk Apparently Twisted uses it for its reactor pattern, so I know I'm on the right track.